# Can't delete a file "The process cannot access the file"

Tags: c#, file, stream, delete-file

I have this code, the idea is to read from a file and the delete the file.

```
                StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path);

                s = sr.ReadLine();
                if ((s != null))
                {
                 sr.ReadLine();
                  do
                   {
                   // I start to read and get the characters

                   }while (!(sr.EndOfStream));
                 }
                 sr.close();
```

and then after close the streamReader,
I try to delete the file but I can't:

> "The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process"

What can I do?

Comment: Is it an excel file or any other?

Comment: The code (fragement) looks overly complicated and somwhat fragile from what you describe is the goal. Show the complete code/function, at least up to the part where you attempt to delete the file.

Comment: it is a txt code, and I try with sr.Dispose() and it doesn't work

Comment: Can you tell what the path variable contains?

Comment: close notepad :)

Comment: Go to the Task Manager and close the process :) or restart your PC. Maybe you've done the debug before add `sr.Close()`.

Comment: I had other process locking my file :S, thx to all people!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try deleting after enclosing your code in a `using` statement as follows:

```
using(  StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path) ) 
{ 
    ...
}
```

If that does not work either, then some other process has locked your file.

Comment: Ah, another happy customer.  Glad to be of help.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use some thing like this

```
using (StreamReader sr= new StreamReader(your Path here))
{
    // do your stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To read a file line by line try the following:

```
using (var reader = new StreamReader(path))
{
    string line;
    while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        // do something with the line that was just read from the file
    }
}

// At this stage you can safely delete the file
File.Delete(path);
```

or if the file is small you can even load all the lines in memory:

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(path);
// Do something with the lines that were read
...
// At this stage you can safely delete the file
File.Delete(path);
```